# android jars. How to build them?

Tags: android

I'm developing an OpenSource project for android which I'm about to upload to github... But one question... I'm developing it with the typical tree source of an Android Project. How can I distribute it with a Jar like it was a Java library?

Thanks!

Comment: this thread would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868546/android-how-to-export-jar-with-resources/9868791#comment12604309_9868791

Comment: But what if I don't want to include resources?

Comment: It may not be a proper use, but a jar without resources would be generated in the bin/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I distribute it with a Jar like it was a Java library?

Run the `jar` command on your classes. Here is one possible Ant task for this:

```
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
    <jar
        destfile="bin/NAME-OF-YOUR-JAR-GOES-HERE.jar"
        basedir="bin/classes"
    />
</target>
```