# How to put an external library project to my one?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use a [svg-android](https://github.com/pents90/svg-android/tree/master/svgandroid) library to work with *.svg files in Android. For the same, I've installed the [apache ant](http://code.google.com/p/winant/), created a folder in workspace called: `SVGAndroid` and then added

```
android.library.reference.1=C:\Android\workspace\SVGAndroid
```

to project.properties file.

There were no documentation for functions in ReadMe, so I'm wondering if the installation correct or not, how to reinstall an external lib in the second case and where are the examples of using svg-android?

Comment: You do know that apache does provide the ant binary right?

Comment: Yes, but *.exe is more convenient.

Comment: not really.. it ideally shouldn't matter. But that is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your including of the project, just include the project into your workspace and in your respective application under the properties of that project just add a dependency on a library that references svgandroid. Make **SURE** to include the files and ensure that the compile class files are present in the final output of the apk. This typically means that you add the project to your build path/order.

Another approach is to just take the entire project and compile it into a jar file and then include that jar in your libs folder and add that dependency on the jar file of that respective project to your core application.

### Useful links

[How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Comment: And how to add a dependency on the jar file and check if it is made right way?

Comment: check the final apk by decompiling or just ensure that its in your build order/path.

Comment: @JoxTraex AFAIK it is not possible to compile an Android project into a `.jar` file.

Comment: The facebook project can be compiled into a jar file. And a lot of this is done with third party libraries, it's very common.. check chartboost, AdX, etc.. Each of these are third party android projects that come in the form of jar files. @niculare

Comment: "And how to add a dependency"?

Comment: Please excercise your google-fu and look up these key words in a statement... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Comment: @JoxTraex I have seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868546/android-how-to-export-jar-with-resources) about exporting an android project as a .jar file, but you say some projects can be exported. Are some special conditions for those which can be exported as a jar file?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to not add the path to the project manually, but from `Project Properties` -> `Android` and you will have a list with all the library projects in the workspace from which you can choose the desired project.

Also I suggest adding in `project.properties` the following line:

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

in order to have all the `AndroidManifest.xml` files of the referenced library projects merged into the main project's manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include  a library file in to your project follow the below steps;

1. Download a jar file and save it in any folder.
2. open your project.
3. Right click--> Build path--> Add External Archives---> Add your external jar file to your project