# How export jar of a android library project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

How do I export a jar of an Android library project with a resource?

I tried this: [How to create jar for Android Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063826/how-to-create-jar-for-android-library-project) but it doesn't work - I get: resource not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of following question.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868546/android-how-to-export-jar-with-resources][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868546/android-how-to-export-jar-with-resources

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to import your library project from:
  `File` --> `Import` --> `Existing code` from the workspace.
- After that for any project for which you want that library:
  Right Click on your project --> `Properties` --> on Left side select `Android`.
- Then click on the `add` button.
- Then the list of your library projects will appear.
  Choose a project from the list and then click on `Apply` and then `OK`.

Comment: Yes thank you, I know the way for add a library in project, but I don't release a source code. I would like the jar file, I can not include resources

Comment: then copy the jar files of your library prjct into your prjct

Answer (score 0):

jar can't contain android resources.

If you need a library with resources, use it as an android library project.